# text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: html, position, alignment, css

I have such html code

```
<li>
  <strong>Name Lastname<span>1</span></strong>
  <span>ok</span>
  <date>Monday, 10th Dec 2012</date>
</li>
```

and css

```
li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
strong {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
strong span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #9c0;
}
date {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 7px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

When I resize window, I want that my span will be always at the right side of the text in strong element. If the window is narrow, text should be overflowed and span visible.

Please see attached images

What I want

[image: What I want 1]

[image: What I want 2]

What I have:

[image: What I have 1]

If I give position absolute for span it works for narrow window, but not for wide (inversely to first solution).

[image: What I have with absolute 1]
[image: What I have with absolute 2]

Kris.

Comment: post your full block html and css. there is no date in you html code now

Answer (score 0):

Place the `span` outside the `strong` tag

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="left">
            <img src="http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/sxi/goes14_firstimage_small.jpg" />
            <strong>Name Lastname Lastname</strong><span>1</span>            
        </div>
         <div class="date">Monday 12 Sept 2012</div>
     </li>
</ul>
​
```

**CSS**

```
 ul{margin:0; padding:0}
li {
  padding: 0 10px; list-style:none
}
.left{
    overflow:auto
}
.left img{float:left; position:relative}
strong {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; margin-right:20px
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #9c0; position:absolute; right:0; top:6px
}
.date{float:right; }
```

​
    ​

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/NPJmjnvS)**

Comment: Thanks Sowmya, but the green bubble is hiding when I resize window. It should be always visible instead of name.

Comment: Please see the first and second image. This is correct behavior, which I can't  code